# Widget crashes when Button created

Tags: android, button, widget

First: I am a Newby. So if it was a surprising easy solution, please don't harass me.

I am new to widgets and i wanted to start doing them. Actually for a Flashlight program.

The problem is: I can create a Widget but when i even just declare a button in the layout file, the widget crashes and the only thing i can see is "Fehler"(means "Error" in german).

Here is the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
        android:minHeight="40dp"
        android:minWidth="40dp"
        android:resizeMode=""
        android:updatePeriodMillis="100"
        android:initialLayout="@layout/widget_switch"
        android:widgetCategory="home_screen">

    </appwidget-provider>
```

The layout file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:background="@drawable/appwidget_dark_bg">

        <button
        android:id="@+id/switchButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textOn="@string/toggle"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

The receiver part of the Manifest is:

```
<receiver

    android:label="Flashlight Widget"
    android:name="MyWidgetProvider" >
    <intent-filter >
        <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.WIDGET_BUTTON" />
    </intent-filter>

    <meta-data                
    android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
    android:resource="@xml/widget_switch" />

</receiver>
```

And the java file, which is in the same package as the MainActivity

```
package com.quicksilver.flashlight;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.Parameters;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;

public class widget_switch extends AppWidgetProvider {

    boolean clicked = true;
    boolean camera_initialized=false;
    Camera mCamera;
    public static String WIDGET_BUTTON = "android.appwidget.action.WIDGET_BUTTON";

    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[]     appWidgetIds) {

        if (!camera_initialized){
                mCamera=Camera.open();
                camera_initialized=true;
        }
        RemoteViews remoteViews = null;
        remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_switch);

        Intent intent = new Intent(WIDGET_BUTTON);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.switchButton, pendingIntent );
    }



    public void onRecieve(Context context, Intent intent) {
     if (WIDGET_BUTTON.equals(intent.getAction()))
        toggleFlashlight();

    }

    private void turnOn() {

        //mCamera = Camera.open();
        Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
        params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH); 
        mCamera.setParameters(params);
        mCamera.startPreview();

    }

    private void turnOff() { 

        //mCamera = Camera.open();
        Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
        params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF); 
        mCamera.setParameters(params);
        mCamera.startPreview();
        //mCamera = Camera.open();
    }

    public void toggleFlashlight () {
        if (clicked){
            clicked = false;
            turnOn();
        }else {
            clicked = true;
            turnOff();

    }
}
```

Logcat:

```
03-24 20:40:07.583: D/AndroidRuntime(11560): Shutting down VM
03-24 20:40:07.583: W/dalvikvm(11560): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41635d40)
03-24 20:40:07.586: E/AndroidRuntime(11560): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-24 20:40:07.586: E/AndroidRuntime(11560): Process: com.quicksilver.flashlight, PID: 11560
03-24 20:40:07.586: E/AndroidRuntime(11560): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver com.quicksilver.flashlight.MyWidgetProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.quicksilver.flashlight.MyWidgetProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.quicksilver.flashlight-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.quicksilver.flashlight-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
03-24 20:40:07.586: E/AndroidRuntime(11560):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2427)
03-24 20:40:07.586: E/AndroidRuntime(11560):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:139)
03-24 20:40:07.586: E/AndroidRuntime(11560):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1286)
03-24 20:40:07.586: E/AndroidRuntime(11560):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-24 20:40:07.586: E/AndroidRuntime(11560):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-24 20:40:07.586: E/AndroidRuntime(11560):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5102)
03-24 20:40:07.586: E/AndroidRuntime(11560):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-24 20:40:07.586: E/AndroidRuntime(11560):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-24 20:40:07.586: E/AndroidRuntime(11560):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
03-24 20:40:07.586: E/AndroidRuntime(11560):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
03-24 20:40:07.586: E/AndroidRuntime(11560):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-24 20:40:07.586: E/AndroidRuntime(11560): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.quicksilver.flashlight.MyWidgetProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.quicksilver.flashlight-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.quicksilver.flashlight-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
03-24 20:40:07.586: E/AndroidRuntime(11560):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
03-24 20:40:07.586: E/AndroidRuntime(11560):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
03-24 20:40:07.586: E/AndroidRuntime(11560):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
03-24 20:40:07.586: E/AndroidRuntime(11560):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2422)
03-24 20:40:07.586: E/AndroidRuntime(11560):    ... 10 more
03-24 20:40:09.361: I/Process(11560): Sending signal. PID: 11560 SIG: 9
```

So, you have tons of Material you can work with. The phone is the Motorola Moto G, and i don't test it on the emulator because its just too slow.

I hope you will find the problem and solve it because im getting a bit frustrated.

Thanks for Answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Actually the original post to that is deleted.)

If you remake the file and select a button as root element it works.

It doesn't respond when its pressed, but that belongs to a different question.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the following:

```
android:name="MyWidgetProvider"
```

to

```
android:name="widget_switch"
```

in the manifest.

Per the [receiver tag documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/receiver-element.html#nm), the name must match the class's name in the package.

Comment: Sry it still doesn't work and i just made it reziseable and its full text seems to be : Error in Loading process

Comment: So the exception is different now when you attempt to run it? Can you please post it?

Comment: log cat says: 03-28 21:57:03.194: I/Adreno-EGL(9130): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:320>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  (N/A)
03-28 21:57:03.194: I/Adreno-EGL(9130): OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.24.00.00
03-28 21:57:03.194: I/Adreno-EGL(9130): Build Date: 11/12/13 Tue
03-28 21:57:03.194: I/Adreno-EGL(9130): Local Branch: 
03-28 21:57:03.194: I/Adreno-EGL(9130): Remote Branch: 
03-28 21:57:03.194: I/Adreno-EGL(9130): Local Patches: 
03-28 21:57:03.194: I/Adreno-EGL(9130): Reconstruct Branch: 
03-28 21:57:03.272: D/OpenGLRenderer(9130): Enabling debug mode 0

Comment: i mean that what the widget says

Comment: I am not sure if that's relevant to the issue. Do you still have `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` in your logcat?

Comment: Ok, does the program launch then, or does it still crash? If it crashes, logcat should say something.

Comment: Could you please update your original thread with more things you have tried and a screenshot of the error?